# Convert Curl command to Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Somehow I don't get it right:

I need to convert this curl command to js axios:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer c193342dae0c433c99f3a33444695930" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "https://api.test.io/api/rest/v2/frontend/jobabo?channel=release72_extern&types=rss::email&email=s.meyer@stest.com" -d '{"audience":["00005"],"jobcategory":["00007"],"location":["4800019"]}'
```

I tried this so far:

```
axios({
            url: 'https://api.test.io/api/rest/v2/frontend/jobabo',
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
                channel : '41629_extern',
                types   : 'email',
                email   : "s.meyer@stest.com",
            },
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            },
            data: {
                "audience": ["00005"],
                "jobcategory": ["00007"],
                "location": ["4800019"],
            },
            auth: {
                username: 'c193342dae0c433c99f3a33444695930',

            }
        }).then(function (response) {

            if(response.data !== undefined && response.data.email === "ok"){
                //success write data to store
                alert("success message");


            }
            else{
                alert("Please check connection.");
            }

        }).catch(function (error) {

            // handle error
            console.log("Connection issue:", error);
        }).then(function () {
            // always executed

        });
```

The request is made... but somehow it is either not a valid post request or the data is not correctly submitted. I am lost. I really tried so many things.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools. Is the request made? Is it formatted the way you expect? Does it get any response at all?

Comment: Look at the Console tab in your browser's developer tools. Are any errors reported?

Comment: yes it does... I receive a SUCCESS. The problem is that that the data array is not received by the api in a correct way.

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: In what way is it received?

Comment: The API is not getting the data object. I receive a 200 Post.

Comment: So look at the data in the body of the request using the network tab of the browser's developer tools. What's wrong with it there?

Comment: The request payload seems correct to me. An object with 3 keys - each with an array as value. However... the api tells me that the data is not received.

Comment: Is my syntax for the axios "post" call correct? ... apart from the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" which I removed

Comment: Maybe you need to define the responseType ?

Comment: is it defined in the curl?

Comment: @AhmedSaber — That's jQuery

Comment: No by default it will be JSON, but I see that you didn't send the same params as the URL does channel=release72_extern&types=rss::email